# Convert Webpack syntax to browserify syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, browserify, webpack

I am learning Flux and am looking at some sample code for an app.config that uses react-router :

```
import React from 'react';  
import Router from 'react-router';  
import { DefaultRoute, Link, Route, RouteHandler } from 'react-router';

import LoginHandler from './components/Login.js';

let App = React.createClass({  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="nav">
        <Link to="app">Home</Link>
        <Link to="login">Login</Link>

        {/* this is the importTant part */}
        <RouteHandler/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

let routes = (  
  <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
    <Route name="login" path="/login" handler={LoginHandler}/>
  </Route>
);

Router.run(routes, function (Handler) {  
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
});
```

This piece of code was written for being used with the Webpack module.

I would try to avoid using it and only use browserify instead.

How do I convert this code? I know I must convert the imports (but am not sure of the syntax), is there more to it?

Here is **my** app.js so far :

```
var React = require('react');
var ProductData = require('./ProductData');
var CartAPI = require('./utils/CartAPI')
var FluxCartApp = require('./components/FluxCartApp.react');


// Load Mock Product Data into localStorage
ProductData.init();

// Load Mock API Call
CartAPI.getProductData();

// Render FluxCartApp Controller View
React.render(
  <FluxCartApp />,
  document.getElementById('flux-cart')
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to convert anything, you can have that code as-is with Browserify and [Babel](https://babeljs.io/):

```
npm install babelify
browserify main.js -t babelify -o dist.js
```

Comment: and if I would like to avoid using babel, is it still easy enough to convert it manually?

Comment: You can convert it to ES5 with Babel, and then continue on the code after the transformation. There are other ES6 features being used there though, plus React JSX syntax, which Babel covers as well. Babel is the [recommended way](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/06/12/deprecating-jstransform-and-react-tools.html) to use React.